# Resolve of invalid GC handle. The handle is from a previous domain. The resolve operation is skipped. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent

Tags: c#, unity3d

Чта это. Ошибка никак не влияет на игру, но немного напрягает

Comment: Она не критическая, но судя по `The resolve operation is skipped` очень даже влияет.

Comment: Чтобы сказать что это, надо знать, где это. Выглядит как Unity что-то хочет достать из неуправляемой памяти выгруженного или другого домена приложения, возможно работа системы кеширования. Лечится грамотным управлением ресурсами, в вашем случае в UI.

Comment: @aepot я благодарен, но что делать если эта ошибка появляется реально рандомно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это может быть связано с использованием `static` полей в скриптах, перестаньте использовать статику. Даже если бы этой ошибки не было, то всё равно бездумная статика - зло.

Немного матчасти [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html), можно еще попробовать [выключить Domain Reloading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DomainReloading.html). С очень большой вероятностью перезагрузка доменов вам в принципе не нужна. А если нет статики, то тогда она еще и ни на что не влияет.

Кстати, в современных .NET, куда Unity рано или поздно затащат, доменов в принципе нет, они не нужны.

Comment: Статики не было вообще. Че то там включил и вроде эта ошибка больше не появлялась

Comment: @Gilly окей, а ответ помог или нет?

Comment: раз ошибки нет - значит помог